# ¿Existe alguna palabra en español para la palabra inglesa "handedness"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Entiendo que "handedness" significa la preferencia de uso de la mano izquierda o derecha. ¿Tenemos en español alguna palabra para referirnos a esto o tenemos que escribir "preferencia de uso de la mano izquierda o derecha"?

Comment: Handedness is quite a general concept in English as well even extended to inanamiate objects like screws when it is, I think, _Sentido de la hélice de la rosca_. Presumably you do not want a word as general as that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Podemos usar la palabra *lateralidad*. No es específica de las manos sino de la parte del cuerpo en general pero supongo que es lo más parecido al término *handedness*.

> **[lateralidad](http://dle.rae.es/?id=My9ZqOL)**
>
> Del fr. *latéralité*, der. de *latéral* 'lateral'.
>
> **1.** f. Preferencia espontánea en el uso de los órganos situados al lado derecho o izquierdo del cuerpo, como los brazos, las piernas, etc.

Comment: Entonces en caso de la pregunta habría que decir "lateralidad derecha" o "lateralidad izquierda".  En el caso del uso de las manos/pies en Colombia simplemente decimos por ejemplo:  "¿Pablo es derecho/diestro o zurdo?".

Comment: Yo también digo zurdo y diestro pero *lateralidad* es la preferencia de un lado sobre otro, no importa cuál. Se podría usan en una frase de este tipo: _La lateralidad en los niños se define alrededor de los 4 años_

Comment: Excelente. Deberías adicionar el ejemplo a la respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

También se puede decir

***dominancia lateral***

https://es.slideshare.net/adefesiosos/desarrollo-de-la-dominancia-lateral

Para mí esta frase me queda mejor en conversación que *lateralidad*.  Un pariente cercano mío, por ejemplo, es un tanto ambidextro, y me explica a veces que tiene una u otra mano *dominante* en tal o cual actividad.  Es un poco como los idiomas.  Prefiero usa el español para hablar de la química pero prefiero usar el inglés para la informática.

Answer (score 0):

!handedness! como ¡Mano dominante!, dominancia, ventaja en alguna de las manos, sin especificar cual.

La pregunta en sí no es normal, "con que mano se te da menor.." a no ser que aquellos precisamente que estén fijándose en alguna de las actividades que estés realizando, entonces hablan, hacen o sacan conclusiones sobre aquello que ven o la *manera que tienes de utilizar las manos*.

Cuando tienes otras habilidades, son los niños cuando se fijan en como haces las cosas, los que de manera especial comienza a preguntarte, cuando ven como coges los lápices de colores, los sueltas y coges otros con la otra mano para seguir dando color a otras partes a la vez. Es cuando te dicen    ¿Qué haces?

Personalmente soy ambidiestro, es decir utilizo las dos manos para escribir, dibujar o coger cosas de forma indistinta y distinta, si bien en algunos deportes suelo utilizar una parte del cuerpo en detrimento de otras, sin embargo en otras actividades las utilizó de manera diferente, incluso a la hora de comer, me es indistinto coger los cubiertos de una u otra forma, pero esas preferencias te las da el tiempo, el uso o la personalidad.

Cuando alguien me observa y ve como cambio de mano o cojo otro color, para continuar escribiendo, las preguntas en cuestión que me hacen son del tipo ¿Con cual de las manos te manejas mejor? o ¿con que mano tienes mas habilidad?, ¿ cual es tu mejor mano? o ¿usas más?.... No me preguntan si soy diestro ó zurdo, ya que eso sería absurdo, pues se ve claro. Si acaso, me preguntan como se llama o cual es el nombre de aquellos que escriben con las dos manos y yo le digo "ambidiestro". Y continúan y siguen preguntando, pero cual es la mano que más te gusta, te duele alguna mano, cual es la mano con la que te manejas en general mejor. ¿ Como puedo hacer eso ?. También sirve para otras articulaciones.

Si alguien tuviera que preguntarme, relacionado con estos casos, la cuestión "handedness", se quedaría un tanto corta. La cuestión importante para mi sería algo parecido a como; ¿ Cual de tus manos es la mano maestra?, ó ¿ Cual de las dos manos es para ti la maestra y cual la aprendiz? Una, es la que levanta y dirige el armazón, el esquema con la que de forma habitual arrancas los procesos y la otra sin dejarla atrás y no menos importante, es la que esta más pendiente de ir confeccionando, cerrando, supervisar y terminar los detalles que se van quedando abiertos. Esto es solo mi punto de vista claro. Saludos.

La cuestión "handedness", salvando las diferencias, es un poco ridícula, pues denota  el poco uso utilizado en ciertos hábitos. Es como si te preguntan a la hora del freno en los coche, sientes lateralidad ó utilizas más bien el pie del embrague a la hora de frenar. Denota una pregunta destinada a aquellos que hacen poco uso de ciertas habilidades, simplemente.